# curl request results in heavy load on the server

Tags: curl, network-traffic

We consume an XML Datafeed by sending cURL requests to the provider's server. They do not allow us to cache, so each pageview is a new cURL request. Twice this year, our server has crashed with the explaination from our server company being that the IP that belongs to the provider's domain is sending us a lot of traffic. Now, it seems to me that by "sending a lot of traffic" that might mean just thier answers to our requests, but then again, if it's actually them sending requests to us, I need to be sure of that before I start hassling their techs to fix a problem that might be on our end. If the problem is on our end, can I throttle the requests? (This is custom coded in PHP. If this is too much in one question, let me know and I'll split it into smaller chunks.)

EDIT:
Here's what my hosting provider said: (They previously thought the /dev/sda drive was failing.)

> Upon rebooting the server into single-user mode, the drives are not
>   reporting any errors. Additionally, all of the filesystems are intact.
>   We rebooted the server and everything came back online properly. I did
>   see that there was a massive load spike on the server at the time that
>   it stopped responding, and that around that time there were a lot of
>   connections form the IP 208.215.218.15. There are also a lot of
>   connections from that IP right now. This is the info on that IP:
>
> Quick Technologies Inc. UU-208-215-218 (NET-208-215-218-0-1)
>   208.215.218.0 - 208.215.218.255 MCI Communications Services, Inc. d/b/a Verizon Business UUNET1996B (NET-208-192-0-0-1) 208.192.0.0 -
>   208.255.255.255
>
> Connections from this IP quickly filled your network and I was forced
>   to null-route connections from this IP in order to keep the network
>   up. If this was somehow legitimate, let me know and I can unblock this
>   IP.
>
> At this time, your sites are up. If you have any questions, or there
>   is anything else I can do for you, please let me know.

Then they gave me a log like this: (local ip changed for privacy)

> root@fbs
>   [~/system-snapshot/system-snapshot-HG-backup-20120604-144747]# grep
>   208.215.218.15 112.log tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:45948 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:45946 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:45922 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:45921 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:45974 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:45973 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:46037 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:46036 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:46033 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:46032 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:46030 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:46029 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:46028 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:46026 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:46067 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:46063 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:46062 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:46061 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:46060 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:46059 208.215.218.15:443 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:40448 208.215.218.15:80 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:40449 208.215.218.15:80 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:40450 208.215.218.15:80 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:40451 208.215.218.15:80 TIME_WAIT -  tcp 0 0 123.123.123.198:40452 208.215.218.15:80 TIME_WAIT -

There were many, many similar lines below this.
They finally answered in another reply:

> Here's some random samples of network traffic for that IP, and the
>   arrows show the direction (and amount of data) FROM your server or TO
>   your server from that IP:
>
> fbs.foobar.net => 208.215.218.15 5.84Kb 3.51Kb 3.19Kb <= 16.7Kb 181Kb
>   92.1Kb
>
> fbs.foobar.net => 208.215.218.15 11.3Kb 23.1Kb 16.2Kb <= 0b 27.9Kb
>   152Kb ...
>
> Currently there are 27 connections from 208.215.218.15, but the
>   traffic is minimal at present, as seen above (5-16.7 Kbs)

So it looks like traffic from them to us is probably limited to responses to our curl requests, but I'm still not 100% clear on that, or why or if this caused the server to stop responding.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is here.  It's also not clear to me why a server would 'crash' when sent a lot of traffic.  You need to do more diagnosis and provide more detail.  What logging do you have, what analysis of traffic for the site do you do, etc.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is here either because I am not really a system admin. Since I'm the web developer, I'm the one that gets to call or write tickets to the hosting company. When I get to work, I'll look up the ticket and post some of the data they gave me from the log.

Comment: It is probably some misuage in your scripts, so they open too much curl connections to other server. Maybe each page has some php code with curl fetch, and whem search engine bot starts downloading all pages from your site it causes to many simultaneous connections.

Comment: I think you're right @Andrei. When I first had the problem I thought that they were sending requests to us, not understanding the flow of data. Now I get it. What I was seeing as them "hitting" our server was just their replies, so it is my script causing the problem. I'll have to throttle the script or otherwise refactor it to send fewer requests.